# "height on something"

Tags: prepositions

I am curious about an English sentence, I've read in the  [German.Stackexchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/expressing-a-persons-height?rq=1):

Someone wrote

> What's the height on that tree? (Authour: J_LV)

and after some discussion

> user6191: There's height on the tree?
>
> J_LV: There's height on the tree? 
>   You do not seem to understand the phrase "What's the height on that tree?" correctly. It's a different usage of the word "on" than what you're thinking of. And it's not incorrect either although I can perfectly understand why it would confuse a fellow German. I'd however still advise you to do your research prior to humorously implying that I misused a word.

the sentence was edited by another stack exchange user to

> What's the height of this tree?

I'm confused by the discussion and cannot find an reliable reference to "being height on". Is it also correct to say **What's the height on that tree?**

Answer (score 4):

To say **there's height on** is a rather unusual way of saying that something or someone is especially high or tall. It's an expression, a way of commenting on the height of an object.

When I saw a recent photograph of a nephew who now towers over his mother, I might well have said: **There's height on that boy**, meaning that he's really grown tall.

Similarly I might comment that **there are muscles on** that lad, meaning that he has grown muscular.

Generally, as you note, we speak about **the height of** an object or mountain but this is in a different context, generally when we are comparing or measuring things. However, you would always ask **what's the height of that tree?** and not **on that tree?**.

Answer (score 3):

The preposition **on** is often spatial in its meaning as in *The cat is on the mat* but it is not exclusively so. **on** can express an attribute relationship.

As Ronald Sole mentions in his answer **on** can be used in contexts where some attribute is unusual or extreme:

> Would you look at the speed on that kid! Man, can he run!

The attribute does not have to be extreme:

> What's the height on that tree?

That could be a simple question, perhaps asked by someone shopping at a landscaping business for things to plant on the grounds of a newly built house, say.

A similar question might be

> Can I get a price **on** three dozen iPads?